# サービスアカウントタイプのOAuthクライアントを利用したGmail APIの実行方法について

Tags: gmail

以下のページを参考に、Google Appsのテナント内のユーザに対して、転送先メールアドレスの設定をしようと思っていますが、APIから応答がエラーとなってしまいます。
developers.google.com/gmail/api/v1/reference/users/settings/forwardingAddresses

試したことは、以下の通りなのですが、誤っている手順や不足している手順がないか、ご教授いただけませんでしょうか。よろしくお願いいたします。

１．OAuthクライアントの作成

Google Developer ConsoleのAPI Managerにアクセスし、タイプが「サービスアカウント クライアント」となるOAuth 2.0 クライアントを作成。作成したクライアントには、「Google Apps のドメイン全体の委任を有効にする」のチェックを入れている。

２．権限の付与

「Google Apps管理画面
　　->セキュリティ  ->詳細設定
　　->APIクライアントアクセスを管理」から、
　作成したクライアントに対して、「https://mail.google.com/」の権限を付与

３．アクセストークン取得

以下のページで公開されているPHPライブラリを使い、アクセストークンを取得しています。
developers.google.com/api-client-library/php/start/installation

アクセストークンを取得するPHPコードは以下の通りです。

```
<?php

require_once realpath(dirname(__FILE__).'/google-api-php-client/src/Google/autoload.php');

$client_email = 'platinum-pager-xxxxxx@appspot.gserviceaccount.com';
$private_key = file_get_contents('MyProject.p12');

$scopes = array("https://mail.google.com/");

$credentials = new Google_Auth_AssertionCredentials(
    $client_email,
    $scopes,
    $private_key
);

$client = new Google_Client();

$client->setAssertionCredentials($credentials);
if ($client->getAuth()->isAccessTokenExpired()) {
  $client->getAuth()->refreshTokenWithAssertion();
}

var_dump($client->getAccessToken());

?>
```

４．Gmail API実行

URL：[https://www.googleapis.com/gmail/v1/users/メールアドレス/settings/forwardingAddresses](https://www.googleapis.com/gmail/v1/users/%E3%83%A1%E3%83%BC%E3%83%AB%E3%82%A2%E3%83%89%E3%83%AC%E3%82%B9/settings/forwardingAddresses)
　メソッド：GET
　ヘッダ：
　　Authorization: Bearer アクセストークン

→このリクエストに対する応答が、以下のエラー応答となります。

応答ステータス：400
　応答本文：

```
{
"error": {
    "errors": [
        {
            "domain": "global",
            "reason": "failedPrecondition",
            "message": "Bad Request"
        }
    ],
    "code": 400,
    "message": "Bad Request"
}
```

Answer (score 1):

さらっと見て気づいた点ですが，，
- もし転送先アドレスを設定したいのならメソッドはPOSTではないでしょうか？
- もう1点，エンドポイント(URL)が正しく設定されていないのではないでしょうか？下記の"メールアドレス"となっている部分は"userId"であるべきです。

```
https://www.googleapis.com/gmail/v1/users/メールアドレス/settings/forwardingAddresses
```

リファレンス : https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/v1/reference/users/settings/forwardingAddresses/create